# Magento 2 Error filtering template: Warning: filesize ()

Tags: magento2, template, filter

Error filtering template: Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://localhost/jaipurbkp/pub/media/catalog/product/s/c/screen_shot_2020-10-03_at_2.37.35_pm.png in C:\wamp64\www\jdrbkp\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php on line 63